# App crashes when editing a record selected via searchbar

Tags: ios, swift

once we have more then 2 records in coredata, if i were to use the search option and select a hotel from search, go to a hotel's ratings page and select an emoji the app crashes giving below error

```
attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'
```

Important files,

**RestaurantMainController** in controller group - **all search bar code** helper function **line 343** onwards, other code in view didload **line 106** onwards

**DetailViewController** in controller folder, **line 162**, how i move to restaurant ratings

**RatingsViewController** **line 44** ,  here if i remove

```
self.restaurant.rating = rating
```

at **line 50** every thing is fine else i get the error

The app works well if i do not use the search bar, but as soon as search bar is used and i update the ratings the app crahses

Code for add/update

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        restaurantMainTable.beginUpdates()
    }
    
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                restaurantMainTable.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                restaurantMainTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
               
            }
            
        case .update:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                restaurantMainTable.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        default:
            restaurantMainTable.reloadData()
            
        }
        
        if let fetchedObjects = controller.fetchedObjects {
            restaurants = fetchedObjects as! [Restaurant]
        }
    }
    
    
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        restaurantMainTable.endUpdates()
        
        
        
    }





@objc func addRatings(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
        let detailReturn = DetailViewController()

               if let rating = sender.titleLabel?.text {
               
                    self.restaurant.rating = rating
           
                
                
            
              
                   if let appDelegat = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
                   
                   
                       appDelegat.saveContext()
                   
                   }
               }
                detailReturn.restaurant = restaurant
 
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailReturn, animated: false)
       
      
       
    }
```

cellforRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = restaurantMainTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantMainViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantMainViewCells
        
        let restaurant = (searchControlInstance.isActive) ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : restaurants[indexPath.row]
       
        cell.restaurantName.text = restaurant.name
        cell.restaurantType.text = restaurant.type
        cell.restaurantLocation.text = restaurant.location
        if restaurant.isVisited == true {
            cell.restaurantHeartImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-tick")
        }
        else {
            cell.restaurantHeartImage.image = nil
        }
        
        if let restaurantImage = restaurant.image {
            cell.restaurantMiniImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
        }
        
       
        return cell
        
        
        
    }
```

**SOLUTION**

So, the problem was such, i type something in the searchbox and the search result will show up based on the filter functions that inserts the matching records in an array, now if i click on any result and move to next page and make changes, the changes happens

If i  now trace back my path, i see the same results, showing up which i found while typing in the search query, the table view needs to be updated here to the original state from where it picked the search results, if not it will give this error

So i added `searchControlInstance.isActive = false`     after i click to search query and move to next view in rowdidselect, this ensures the error is gone

credits - purebreadd

Comment: The error shows that your are trying to delete row1 from a tableView, when there is only 1 row. The resulting tableView would have 0 rows. You should make sure when you delete/add rows to a tableView you are also updating the dataSource it's referring to. My guess is that after you search, the dataSource your tableView is using has not been updated (using data from before the search) (try updating the dataSource & reloading the TV)... If you would like to post more code here (search function, dataSource, rowForItemAt) it would be easier to help. I'm not going to download your unknown file lol

Comment: @purebreadd -thanks, i have added the code where the coredata add/update takes place, also the function where the error occurs, if i remove this.restaurant.rating = rating the error is no more there

Comment: @pureadd - i was able to solve the issue with your suggestion, thanks, i updated. my question

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers :)